# iOS: Core data performBlock makes UI irresponsive

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I just wanted to be clear about core data private context. I am trying to insert 20k record using private context (NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType). But as soon as 'Insert 20k records' button is tapped UI thread hangs.

```
- (IBAction)insertRecords:(id)sender {


[[CoreDataStore privateContext] performBlock:^{

    NSLog(@"Starting to insert 20k records...");
    for (int i = 0 ; i < 20000; i++)
    {
        NSManagedObject *newManagedObject = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Event" inManagedObjectContext:[CoreDataStore privateContext]];
        [newManagedObject setValue:[NSDate date] forKey:@"time"];
    }
    NSError * error = nil;
    NSLog(@"Inserted 20k records to managed object context");
    [[CoreDataStore privateContext] save:&error];
    NSLog(@"Save context command fired");

}];

NSLog(@"returning from insert method");
}
```

changes from private context are being merged to main context here

```
- (void)contextDidSavePrivateQueueContext:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    @synchronized(self) {

    [self.mainContext performBlock:^{
        NSLog(@"merging changes to main context.....");
        [self.mainContext mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:notification];
        NSLog(@"merged changes to main context");
    }];
}
}
```

Below is log window output when I hit insert button:

```
2014-08-04 14:54:12.431 CoreDataDrillDown[11323:90b] returning from insert method
2014-08-04 14:54:12.431 CoreDataDrillDown[11323:1403] Starting to insert 20k records...
2014-08-04 14:54:12.506 CoreDataDrillDown[11323:1403] Inserted 20k records to managed object context
2014-08-04 14:54:12.785 CoreDataDrillDown[11323:90b] merging changes to main context.....
2014-08-04 14:54:12.786 CoreDataDrillDown[11323:1403] Save context command fired
2014-08-04 14:54:27.019 CoreDataDrillDown[11323:90b] merged changes to main context
```

For more than 15 sec UI was irresponsive. I want to know the reason why?

With below approach suggested by https://stackoverflow.com/users/817182/thom-ek and https://stackoverflow.com/users/2128900/micha%c5%82-ciuba, insertion is quick and does not freeze UI but changes are not getting saved to disk, not sure why.

```
//writerContext has persistent store coordinator, so it should write data to disk but it 
//is not writing any changes to disk.???????
 -(NSManagedObjectContext *)writerContext
    {
      if (!_writerContext)
    {
        _writerContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];
        _writerContext.persistentStoreCoordinator  =  [(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] persistentStoreCoordinator];
    }
    return _writerContext;
}
//mainContext is being used with NSFetchedResultController
-(NSManagedObjectContext *)mainContext
{
    if (!_mainContext)
    {
        _mainContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSMainQueueConcurrencyType];
        _mainContext.parentContext = [self writerContext];
    }
    return _mainContext;
}

//performBlock is being called on privateContext
-(NSManagedObjectContext *)privateContext
{
    if (!_privateContext)
    {
        _privateContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];
        _privateContext.parentContext = [self mainContext];
    }
    return _privateContext;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Main problem is that mainContext is still tied to mainQueue, so it will wait for this huge merge.

There are good articles about asynchronous saves: on [Cocoanetics](http://www.cocoanetics.com/2012/07/multi-context-coredata/) and [ObjC.io](http://www.objc.io/issue-2/common-background-practices.html).

Other solution is just to reset mainContext and reload all tableViews (you don’t show all of 20k records to user at once).

Comment: As per your links I tried using a separate private queue for data writing operation. PrivateWriterContext has persistentStoreCoordinator is parent of MainContext and MainContext is parent of PrivateContext. But still UI freezes although time came down from 15 to 12 sec. Your second suggestion is about resetting context, I am using FethedResultController where should I reset the context and how it will make UI not to freeze?

Comment: I'm not sure why do you need to insert 20000 rows at once. Is it pre-populating the database after the app's been launched for the first time? If so, you don't need to do the merge at all. Instead, insert objects in the background using PrivateWriterContext, and create a main context (as a child of PrivateWriterContext) after the insertion is finished.

Comment: In Cocoanetics solution you have 3 contexts, not 2.

Comment: Reseting context - `[mainContext reset]` just after import has finished. Then post event about finished import to all tableViewControllers displaying these data and call `[tableView reload]`. Of course, if you are editing something during reset you will have to reload these records too. Anyway, safer solution is to use batch saving every N records.

Comment: @thom_ek I think FetchedResultsController fetches results in batches of given size, in my case it is 20.

Comment: @thom_ek please see my edits I have added the code for 3 context solution. But changes are not being written to disk. Table View getting update correctly while app is active but during relaunch nothing is there.

Comment: @MichałCiuba please see my edits, changes are not being written to disk I don't understand why?

Comment: are you sure you are saving changes in the `writerContext`, not the `privateContext`? Or you aren't getting an error when saving context?

Comment: @MichałCiuba since writerContext has the persistent coordinator so when I say save: on privateContext, changes are merged to mainContext(child of writerContext) and finally writerContext should write it to disk?

Comment: @devgr save: on privateContext only merges changes with mainContext. Now you have to call save: on mainContext to merge them with writerContext.

Comment: @devgr ofcourse that NSFetchedResultController fetches them in batches, but it will fetch them from mainContext which may have old data - that’s why, you have to reset mainContext and refetch data from disk.

Comment: @thom_ek since privateContext is child of mainContext all changes are propagated to mainContext and finally NSFetchResultsController is notified and its delegate methods get called and in - (void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller, I am reloading the tableView so I won't have old data. )

Comment: @thom_ek where should I call save: on mainContext?

Comment: @devgr we are talking about two different solutions :) If you use parent contexts approach you will NOT have to call `reset`. You just call `save:` on each context just one by one - you have this in Cocoanetics  example in chapter 'Parent/Child Contexts’. You will call `reset` only when NOT using context chaining.

Comment: Yeah, both are different thing.